# See other DEVICES running the APP in a virtual CAMERA replacing them with a MASK

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine4

I want to design an game app that can "sense" or see other players running the game and see them through my screen like a radar.

Is it possible to see other people I am pointing at with my phone that are running the app and show them as a 3D Cube for example. Show their exact location, some sort of like Pokemon GO?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is "yes".
The real answer is that it's quite complex.

Somehow you will need to connect to the other players device and get them to send their GPS location. Once you have this you need to apply your device's location and orientation to find the location  relative to your device.

Bear in mind that GPS accuracy is going to be around 10m so you could easily see someone in front of you when they are actually behind you.

A good starting point would be looking into networking between devices. Unity provides Netcode for GameObjects but you will almost certainly need a dedicated server to facilitate the connections.

Also, you would need to be aware of privacy issues.